# Going to random entry in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am making an app that shows a ListView, and when the user touches one of the items in the ListView, an AlertDialog pops up. This all works fine. I want a button to appear on the AlertDialog called Random. This button is supposed to open a random item in the ListView, however, the AlertDialog closes and nothing else happens when i click the button.

I am tryinhg to use the .setSelection method in ListView, is that method correct? Here is my relevant code:

```
   //This is all in the listView.setOnItemClickListener
ad.setButton("Random", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int low = 0;
                        int high = 16;
                        int R = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
                        listView.setSelection(R);
```

Comment: From one AlertDialog, you want to open another AlertDialog?

Comment: @Chitrang Yes that is what i want. is that possible?

Comment: As I can see first AlertDialog is possible. Then can you tell me what code you have in list click item event, that you need to pass to second AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ListView's [smoothScrollToPosition(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) to scroll to a particular location in the list.

Comment: But would there be a way to automatically open the AlertDialog of the random location?

Comment: try saving a reference in the getView() once it's scrolled to position, then call view.performClick().

Comment: is getView() a method of ListView, or another element?